# Parameter meaning in JBoss seam

Tags: jakarta-ee, seam2, seam-gen

I am relatively new to seam application framework. I used `seam-gen` to generate entity and view files (*.xhtml, *.page.xml) and observed a few things.

1. {viewId}List.page.xml file has something like `<param name="from"/>`. What does this mean? I see this param is being referred in {viewId}List.xhtml for rendering and for some other things as `empty from`.
2. {viewId}Edit.page.xml and {viewId}.page.xml files has something like `<param name="{viewId}From"/>`. What does this mean? This is also referred in the corresponding xhtml files for doing empty checks.

I tried to get the meaning of these, but I did not get it.
Can somebody explain to me what exactly they mean?

Thanks in advance.